# Idiomatic translation of the book title "I Know This Much Is True" into Russian

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

The phrase “this much” is explained here:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272326/what-does-i-know-this-much-is-true-mean

The Russian translation of this book title is: "Я знаю что это правда". The meaning of "this much" was lost in translation — as if the title was "I know this is true".

What would the Russian equivalent of "this much" be in this context?

Comment: I'm not Russian, so I'm reluctant to provide this as a formal answer, but it seems to me that this could more accurately be rendered with the particle **хоть** somewhere in the sentence. The meaning is that the speaker has *some* information, maybe not all of it, but they're sure that what they *do* know is true. Great question! I'm curious to see what the natives come up with.

Comment: Perhaps "Я знаю что хотя бы это правда" .   "хотя бы это" means that at least this part of the story is true and I know that.

Comment: That's exactly what it means 

Comment: I believe the writer gives an account of their life, including a lot of twists, secrets and deception, so it's hard for them to know what true and what isn't. But they're claiming in the title, that was they wrote, to the best of their knowledge, is in fact true.

Comment: Я знаю, что уж это-то правда.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, two compulsory notes:

1. Show titles (as well as movie titles, book titles, character nicknames etc.) are a marketing device. The correctness of their translation is not the first goal, and not even the tenth. The primary goal is to make the viewer tune in (buy a ticket, put the book in their shopping cart, etc.).
2. Even in the original language, show titles are brief sentences that, at least on the poster, lack any context. Phrases like "Enemy mine", "Up the down staircase", "American beauty" don't make a lot of sense until you've watched the movie or read the book. Other titles don't make a lot of sense even after that.

That said, *in some contexts*, "I know this much is true" can be translated as:

1. *Что правда, то правда*

   > "I didn't do it! I couldn't even walk!" "I know this much is true. He had broken his leg and was wearing a plaster cast". // *— Это не я! Я и ходить-то не мог! — Что правда, то правда. Он сломал ногу и был в гипсе.*
2. *Знаю одно*

   > "I know this much is true: whatever she does, she does it for the money" // *Я знаю одно: что бы она ни делала, всё ради денег*.

I haven't watched the show or read the book and can't tell if these translations would make a catchy title, or if they would make sense in the context of their plots.

Answer (score 5):

> What would the Russian equivalent of "this much" be in this context?

I'd like to suggest some possible translations of this idiom, that refer to common speech patterns:

- **Это я знаю наверняка** - literally *"This I know for sure"*; derived directly from "Я знаю наверняка", which *Reverso* [suggests for "I know this much is true"](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/i+know+this+much). If you omit the pronoun *"это"* ("this"), you make it sound more pleasant: *"Знаю я наверняка"*. Other versions of this off the top of my head are *"Известно мне наверняка"* and *"То, что я знаю наверняка"*.
- **Одно лишь знаю точно** - literally *"I know only one thing for sure"*, but very idiomatic.

  - **Лишь [одно я знаю точно](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)** - literally *"Only one thing I know for sure"*; paraphrase of the same sentence to include the pronoun *я* ("I").
- **[Знаю лишь то](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C+%D1%82%D0%BE), что это правда** - literally *"All [I] know is that it's true"*.
- **Могу сказать, что это правда** - literally *"[I] can say this is true"*; refers to [*"могу сказать [лишь одно]"*](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: I think "Это я знаю наверняка" and  "То, что я знаю наверняка" are the best, however all other  examples are equally good.

Comment: I would vote for "Одно я знаю точно".

Comment: As a native English speaker, I agree with Sergey.

Comment: +1, _одно я знаю точно_ has a nice ring to it

Comment: I think  "То, что я знаю наверняка" is the best.  "То" doesn't restrict to "Одно" (one part of the story) and "Это" again, has some restrictive feel to it, just like  "Одно", while "То" is more inclusive, yet doesn't mean the "entire".

Answer (score 1):

- Что знаю точно
- В чём уверен

Both phrases imply that there's something else beyond what's being said that the author isn't sure of.

Comment: +1 for "В чём уверен", nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

The most exact equivalent would be:  "Готов поручиться" or "За что поручусь".

- "Вот за что поручусь - так за его честность."
- "За его порядочность готов поручиться."

An old-fashioned equivalent "Бьюсь об заклад" sounds more emphatic, but allows for a probabilistic interpretation and carries a connotation of betting. In a narration about the pre-revolutionary era, it would be possible to say:

- "Побьюсь об заклад, что он прибудет к обедне."

Our contemporaries, however, seldom use this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something idiomatic, try this:

> Что знаю, то знаю.

The meaning is 'I may not know much, but *this* I know for sure'.

P.S. Additionally, that phrase, being shorter, would look better in the title, as has already been pointed out by @Quassnoi in his answer.